# How to remap MacBook keys

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, applescript, keybindings, game-center

So, I play a game and I am unable to quickly reach my <kbd>6</kbd>,<kbd>7</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd>,<kbd>9</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> keys.

Is there any way that I could revamp my keyboard keys so that, for example :

- <kbd>z</kbd> would result in the same keystroke as my <kbd>6</kbd>
- <kbd>x</kbd> results in <kbd>7</kbd>
- <kbd>c</kbd> results in <kbd>8</kbd>
- <kbd>`</kbd> results in <kbd>9</kbd>
- <kbd>r</kbd> results in <kbd>0</kbd>.

I tried using *key flipper* and the keyboard setting to change the shorts for text but all that allows you to do is change function keys and that didn't lead me anywhere.

Does a program exist, or can I make an AppleScript that allows me to have such a function?

Answer (score 3):

I use [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) for this purpose. The W key on my keyboard is a bit finicky so I use Karabiner-Elements to get around this.

After installing Karabiner-Elements, create a new profile.

[image: Profile]

Then add mappings to this profile.

[image: Mappings]

Finally, use the menu bar to switch between this profile and the default one.

[image: Menu bar]

Answer (score 1):

One way to remap keys like this is to make a custom keyboard layout with the app [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Comment: I've tried doing this but I seem unable to do so when I tried making my Z=6 and then pressed my Z key I just got a Z keystroke, not the desired 6 @tom